# Spring cannot find entity when running threads in unit test

Tags: java, spring, jpa, testing

I have a unit tests for a Spring application which looks basically like this:

```
@Test
@Transactional
public void myTest() {
    long id = createAndFlushMyEntity();
    doSomething();
}
```

This test (and the application itself) are working fine. However, when I put my code in a thread, it doesn't work anymore:

```
@Test
@Transactional
public void myTest() {
    long id = createAndFlushMyEntity();
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            doSomething();
        }
    }.start();   
}
```

I get the following exception:

```
javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find BankConnection with id 1003
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration$Ejb3EntityNotFoundDelegate.handleEntityNotFound(Ejb3Configuration.java:157)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:212)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:262)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:150)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1092)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1019)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:672)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:490)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.replace(EntityType.java:354)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractType.replace(AbstractType.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.type.TypeHelper.replace(TypeHelper.java:211)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.copyValues(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:409)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:282)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:151)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:914)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:898)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:902)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.merge(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:889)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:241)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy66.merge(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:361)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.saveAndFlush(SimpleJpaRepository.java:372)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:344)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:329)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:155)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.LockModeRepositoryPostProcessor$LockModePopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(LockModeRepositoryPostProcessor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy120.saveAndFlush(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy121.updateState(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

So inside of my thread, Spring/JPA cannot find the entity I created right before. If I remove the thread, everything works fine and the entity is there. I can also do something like this:

```
@Test
@Transactional
public void myTest() {        
    long id = createAndFlushMyEntity();
    assertEntityIsPresent(id); // works
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            assertEntityIsPresent(id); // doesn't work!
            doSomething();
        }
    }.start();   
}
```

The test itself has a `@Transactional` annotation. I also flush my JPA repository before calling the thread. So the entity should definitely be there (in my opinion). But it isn't.

Any ideas?

My goal is to test the `doSomething` method with multiple threads. Maybe there is some more elegant way to do that as by creating threads by hand?

EDIT: `doSomething` simply sets a property to the entity:

```
doSomething() {
    Entity entity = repository.findOne(1L); // entity is NULL!
    entity.setState("state");
    repository.saveAndFlush(entity);
}
```

Comment: Because it isn't there... There is no commit so nothing outside of the current running transaction can see the data. The thread is outside the scope of the transaction (transactions are thread bound).

Comment: So how can I do a commit? I thought `saveAndFlush` would do that?

Comment: No flush != commit it only issues the queries both nothing is committed. Also if you commit your data will be permanently in the database not sure if that is what you want. What is it that you want to test?

Comment: I use an H2 database for testing, so it would be OK to commit the transaction. I want to test the following: It is only allowed to set certain states to the entity, e.g. if the state is "CANCELED", it is not allowed to set the state "SUCCESSFUL". I want to write an integration test for that (not only call the setter of the entity), since I want to test the whole process.

Comment: Then setup the data before your test (instead of inside your test) and imho that shouldn't depend on the state in the database but of the actual object... So not sure why you want a thread to test it (or what you think you additionally get with the thread but complexity in  your testcase).

Comment: Thank you for your advise, first! I will test it soon. I want the thread, because we had the situation that a customer was able to execute some action (which sets the state) and was somehow able to cancel the action and execute it again or do it in parallel in another tab. I hope to get the same situation when I run threads.